# TFS: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I try to check-in to TFS I get an error ([TFS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhbON.png)) stating: "There is not enough space on the disk." The error always points to resx files on my local C: drive. The files are each only 1.35MB in size and there is approx 200GB free on my hard-drive. When I first got this problem, I tried restarting visual studio, which did not work. I then restarted my PC. After a restart, I was able to do a check-in and I was able to work away as normal (thinking a restart had solved the issue) until I needed to do another check-in containing a large resx. The same error is thrown. I tried restarting but I am no longer able to do a check-in with the error pointing to resx.

I have tried clearing the TFS cache on my PC etc but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

How do I resolve this issue? Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?
Is this a server problem? Other developers in my organisation are having the same issue with other repositories.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Where is TFS installed? I presume its on a server somewhere? If so have you checked in there to see if their is sufficient space. I am assuming all files on the C drive is your local working folder so the issue will be when you check in your changes which TFS looks to update on its own server, where it is lacking space.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this error is in fact linked to disk space on the server. The error reported by TFS is misleading.

I hope this is of benefit to someone else.

Comment: Same happened here, due to accidentally packaging way more than expected into the artifact.